# Can I update a question after getting a reply?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

I have asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950012/console-not-opening-when-pressing-ctrlf7-in-visual-c-sharp-2010-express/11950100#11950100) and have received a good answer. The answer suggests that I change the code but even when changing it to what is suggested, it does not work. Nevertheless I feel that this is a step forward from before. Can I update the question with this new code or should I ask a new updated question? If I update the question it might confuse people as there will be a discrepancy with the previous reply.

Comment: The answer was updated a few seconds ago (literally as I was checking it out), read it and see if it sufficiently answers your question now.

Comment: @YannisRizos I am asking this not specifically for this question but as a general rule just to be clearer on what is acceptable or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, technically, you can always edit a question.

However, if you have answers that are directed to the original version of the question and the edit will invalidate the answers, you should ensure you edit in a way that doesn't do that.

One way is to add updates at the bottom of the original question.

However, think carefully if this is still the same question - if not you should ask a new question and possibly link to the question the inspired it.

With the specific scenario you describe, a comment on the answer is appropriate (something along the lines of "thanks, tried it but it didn't work. I got the following errors/symptoms").

Comment: Totally agreed. But a caveat: if commenting on an answer, please don't overload a comment with the code you tried, the error message you received, a stack dump, etc. If it's anything non-trivial it's much better suited as an addendum to the question (and maybe a comment on the answer to alert the person that your edit was about their answer).