# Politely making people ask another question

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it appropriate to suggest a user start a new question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92665/when-is-it-appropriate-to-suggest-a-user-start-a-new-question)

I have had tons of questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797487/hibernate-sessionfactory-becomes-null-when-trying-to-use-it-by-invoking-a-method) where, once I've successfully answered, the asker gets another error/exception/problem, and asks another (not unrelated, but IMHO out of context) question in the comments.

This results in edits to the question and of course, my answer is now out of context and by consequence it does not solve all the problems the user is having.

How can we stop such a thing, and *still* get the points from the question?

Related questions:

[Can I update a question after getting a reply?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143456/can-i-update-a-question-after-getting-a-reply)

[How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Not that I am an expert on this but I think you did the right thing.

Comment: You can't _stop_ this kind of thing, though many times if the OP comments back about the new error, you can gently hint that they can ask a new question about the new issue. After a search, of course ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the OP is asking an entirely separate question that he simply thought of as a result of an answer, and it's not a direct clarifying question on the answer, then it does belong in another question.  You should post a comment to the OP that this new question belongs in a new question and roll back the edit on the OP (possibly giving them a bit of time to do it themselves, if you want to be polite).

If the edit is simply adding more details to the current problem, basically adding information that really should have been included to begin with and that the OP just didn't know (or choose not to) include before, such as restrictions on what can or can't be used ("I don't have access to version 3, sorry, that solution won't work") then then the edit should stay, and you should do your best to update your answer.